# Moving data from AJAX output to HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm been looking around to find the answer, I don't know if it's a bit of terminology I'm missing or it's just not possible, so apologies if this is duped, I have been reading and testing all day.

I have a html form on a page and I am grabbing some details through AJAX. Basically looking up a persons demographics to see if it's already in the database. This is matching/search all four demographic fields for matches, that side works fine. What I want if the user sees the match they want to be able to click in it then the form to auto populate the fields and put the ID into a hidden field to submit with a form.

This involves confidential information so I am only going to do a brief summary of what I'm trying to do with the Code.

```js
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");// code for IE6, IE5
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","patientSelect.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

function fillValues(){

  var jsSurname = document.getElementById('jsSurname').innerHTML;
  var jsForename = document.getElementById('jsForename').innerHTML;
  var jsGender = document.getElementById('jsGender').innerHTML;
  var jsDoB = document.getElementById('jsDoB').innerHTML;

    window.alert("yep");

    document.getElementById('PatientSurname').value = jsSurname;
    document.getElementById('PatientForename').value = jsForename;
    document.getElementById('PatientGender').value = jsGender;
    document.getElementById('PatientDateOfBirth').value = jsDoB;

}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    Forename: <input type="text" id='PatientForename' value='' onkeyup="showUser(this.value)">
    Surname: <input type="text" id='PatientSurname' value='' onkeyup="showUser(this.value)">
    Date of Birth: <input type="date" id='PatientDateOfBirth' value='' onkeyup="showUser(this.value)">
    Gender: <input type="text" id='PatientGender' value='' onkeyup="showUser(this.value)">
    <input type="Hiddden"
    <p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint" ></span></p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here the fun part, there is one issue, for a reason which is unfortunately rational in this situation, I can't use JavaScript libraries, just straight vanilla code. So please bear that in mind with your answers and thanks in advance for the help.

Edit; apologies for the late reply; I am actively working in a busy environment as I also have provide tech support (so much fun as programmer) and have regular meetings with various management types.

The code is as complete as needs to be, there rest of the code is just forms section off and hidden until the user completes the pervious set of fields.

I can grab the patientSelect.php when I get home but it really is just a database call and output. I don’t need the code fixing necessarily (I know the above is crap/broke) as I would be able to sort if I know what I need to do.  The fillValue Function is right there in the code.

If someone would be kind of enough to confirm it’s possible and a pointer in the right direction.

Mawg. Is there, and do you know the name of the function, I could backwards engineer if I knew what I was looking for.

Comment: That rules out the obvious Angular or Vue, then :-/

Comment: So, where are you calling your function `fillValues()`? What does your ajax actually return? What are those `document.getElementById('js***')` elements?

Comment: You also have some broken HTML `<input type="Hiddden"` (never closes) and "hidden" is spelled with two d's, not three.

Comment: You can give us a full summary example and just make dummy values for your information. I would be calling `fillValues(data)` when my ajax call comes back successful and pass in the data retrieved from the server. I don't quite see where your server data is or where you even use `fillValues()`

Comment: Asked for clarification an hour ago without a peep from the OP at all. I'm out... (and I voted to close for the lack of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))